# Unable to Access Wordpress PHP Admin to change Admin User Password via Google Cloud Platform Virtual Instance One Click Install

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

For some reason I am not able to access both my Wordpress admin login... as well as the /phpmyaccount or /phpmyadmin to get to the MySQL... I am unable to receive any emails to reset password as well.

I'm done this a Google Cloud Platform instance, using the one click install for Wordpress. SO I can see the password right in front of me, but it is NOT working?

Anyone experience this before? And ideas how else I can access my SQL Database? or change my wordpress login details? Thank You!

This is supposed to be my database but i cannot access it? http://XX.XXX.XXX.XXX/phpmyadmin

Comment: a common issue when copying the password from GCP UI and then trying to pass it to the wordpress instance is that a space is copied before or after the password, as the issue seems to be a "wrong" password verify for this kind of typos

Comment: okay - so add a space before or after the password when trying to log into wordpress or maybe remove a space?

Comment: yeah, verify if when copying the password you are not getting an additional space and remove it

Answer (score 0):

If you used [WordPress on Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/wordpress) then after you deployed your instance you can see the credentials under GCP console -> Home -> Tools -> Deployment Manager -> Deployments -> [Your deployment name, something like wordpress-1] and there you will see all the details like:

```
Site address
Admin URL
WordPress MySQL user
WordPress MySQL password (Temporary)
MySQL root user
MySQL root password (Temporary)
WordPress Admin user
WordPress Admin password (Temporary)
Instance
Instance zone
Instance machine type
```